# Word document versions in Mac version of Office?

Tags: macos, mac, microsoft-word

In the windows version of Microsoft Office (at least in Word 2003) it is/was possible to create a "versioned" document - essentially creating many versions of the document within the same document. This way you can track earlier versions (a potentially big security risk).

I wanted to check if a document we were working on had this feature enabled, but I could not find this option in Microsoft Word for Mac 2011, and all my searching endeavors were fruitless. Is this feature at all in the Mac version? And is it still present in current Windows versions of Word?

Comment: I don't know about that feature, but *Review* isn't what you're looking for is it?

Comment: If it has something to do with "Track changes", commenting, and accepting changes, then no.